# Add extra result to Association Collection Proxy result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic

I have two models,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: user
end
```

I'm using `formtastic gem`, consider in `edit` action of `users_controller`. All required `user` and associated `posts` attributes of the form will be prefilled by formtastic form

code:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :name %>

  <%= f.inputs :posts do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :title %>
    <%= p.input :comment %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

For instance i'm having a `@user` and two `posts` associated. 
while doing `@user.posts`, the result be like.

```
 [
  [0] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a20> {
                   :id => 3,               
                :title => 'Hello World',
              :comment => 'Long text comes here'
  },
  [1] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a41> {
                   :id => 5,               
                :title => 'Hello World 2',
              :comment => 'Long text comes here too'
  }
]
```

So the form will contain two posts field to edit.

Actually, I want another blank post form before those two posts.

This can be easy achieved by inserting  a new empty `post` object to `@object.posts` result at 0th position.

So, the `@object.posts` result i want should exactly look like,

```
    [
      [0] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a50> {
                       :id => nil,               
                    :title => nil,
                  :comment => nil
      },
      [1] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a20> {
                       :id => 3,               
                    :title => 'Hello World',
                  :comment => 'Long text comes here'
      },
      [2] #<Post:0x0000000aa53a41> {
                       :id => 5,               
                    :title => 'Hello World 2',
                  :comment => 'Long text comes here too'
      }
    ]
```

Any solutions to get this structure from  `@user.posts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `#edit` action do something like :

```
def edit
  #... your code
  @user.posts << Post.new
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I found other way around, 

on doing `@user.posts.build` and `@user.posts` builds and adds an another new empty object to the results objects.

Is there any option to sort these results based on id, without using a default scope in `Post` model?